# Button background color toggle

Tags: javascript, html, button, background-color

I have been trying to toggle the background-color property of a button onclick but the color only changes once and does not toggle back and forth. Below is the code.

```
function btnColor(btn, color) {
var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(244,113,33)") {
        property.style.backgroundColor=color;
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(244,113,33)";
    }
}

<input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="Housing" onclick="toggleLayer('transparent1');btnColor('btnHousing','rgb(255,242,0)');" />
```

Comment: Console.log `property.style.backgroundColor` just before `if`, you'll see what the value actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the `background-color` of an element is reported differently in browsers, either rgb, rgba (with, or without, spaces) in hex or in HSL...

So the button will likely never satisfy the `if` condition, meaning it will *always* go to the `else`.

With that in mind, I'd suggest using a class-name to keep track of the un/toggled state:

```
function btnColor(btn, color) {
var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.className !== 'toggled') {
        property.style.backgroundColor=color;
        property.className = 'toggled'
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(244,113,33)";
        property.className = '';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mX35z/).

Of course, if we're using the `class` of the element, we might as well use CSS to *style* the element:

```
function btnColor(btn) {
var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.className !== 'toggled') {
        property.className = 'toggled'
    }
    else {
        property.className = '';
    }
}
```

With the CSS:

```
#btnHousing {
    background-color: rgb(255,242,0);
}

#btnHousing.toggled {
    background-color: rgb(244,113,33);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mX35z/1/).

The previous JavaScript could be simplified (using the same CSS) to:

```
function btnColor(btn) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    property.className = 'toggled' == property.className ? '' : 'toggled';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mX35z/3/).

Comment: What do you suggest I use?

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution (JS, CSS and HTML in order).
You setup a class in CSS, then select the button (yes the JS could have been done in one line) and toggle the class.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");


button1.addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.body.classList.toggle("colorred");

});
```

```css
.colorred {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Change color to background</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />


</head>

<body>
    <button>Click me!</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```