# Repeatedly Toggle Div Background Color On Click Using Inline Vanilla JavaScript on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, toggle, background-color

*To the reader looking from help: Each of the first 4 solutions worked for me, and the suggested question shows potential. I picked Hunsnul Amand's code because it allows for easy expansion of colors in a JavaScript string, and toggles through all three colors mentioned in the problem below. I like the way this sets up the possibility of additional or random colors later. The other three solutions on this page rely on various snippets of JavaScript toggling between additional classes made in CSS.  Ranjeep and Keith's snippets use this in very simple and clean code that's easy to follow. Jateen makes use of the .toggle and ++> elements, which are useful as well. His code was also easy to follow. *

Thank You for checking this out. I'm trying to do something that seems like a very basic skill, but am having trouble finding the specific syntax or code that will cause a webpage to repeatedly toggle the background color of a circular div on a click rather than on a button using Vanilla JavaScript. I've tried too many iterations to post here, and received various effects from trying to modify similar projects to my needs, but haven't been able to get the div's background color to toggle.

background: I started with a sample project that lets you cause a div shaped in a circle with a red background to disappear by setting the background color to "none." I'd like to change the code to something that will instead allow a repeated toggle of the circular div's background color between either red to blue, or at least from red to none and back again.

```
<!-- This document should let you toggle a circle's color between 
    red and blue using vanilla JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. 
    The circle is an HTML div shaped and colored in CSS, 
    and given the toggle function that changes the div's color 
    in JavaScript.
    Biggest need: A JavaScript toggle funciton that alternates 
    the color of a div when the user clicks on the div.-->

Mini Challenge: Disappearing Circles
minichallenge.html!
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning Javascript</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>
            #circle {
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                border-radius:100px;
                background-color:red;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="circle"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           /*original JavaScript Project*/ 
           document.getElementById("circle").onclick=function() {
                        document.getElementById("circle").style.display="none";
                } 
            /* New JS: Purpose: A JavaScript toggle funciton that alternates 
    the color of a div when the user clicks on the div.-
            
            var userClick = document.getElementById("circle").onclick=function() {
            var noDiv = document.getElementById("circle").style.display="blue";
            var redDiv = document.getElementById("circle").style.display="red";
            
            -Pseudocode-: 
            if userClick 
                noDiv
            else redDiv; */
        </script>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks Again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button background color toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050054/button-background-color-toggle)

Comment: Thanks to Reyno for the helpful suggestion of the other thread. The difference is that I'm trying to make the div itself toggle colors when clicked. While a little code modding may yield the result I'm looking for, I'm really really new at this, and such code modding of other solutions have failed, I am looking for a solution that's as specific as possible. Thank You for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of many solutions. In your script try this.

```js
  let i = 0;
  const colors = ["blue", "red", "transparent"];

  document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i++;
    if (i == colors.length) i = 0;
  };
```

This way you can add as many colors as want to the colors array and it will work.

Comment: Wow, I'm glad you took the time to help me. I'll plug it in and see how it works for my project. You made it able to switch from blue, to red, and to transparent. How Cool. Thanks.

Comment: I picked yours as my solution because you made it easy to add new colors in an array. It shows you really understand JavaScript and programming. It's a direction that I didn't know about yet. I'll be studying this code. I'll be studying this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.bg-none` class in you css. Then `toggle` that class onclick of the element. I have updated the code, please chekc

```
<style>
 .bg-none{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
</style>

<script>
 document.getElementById("circle").onclick=function() {
                        document.getElementById("circle").classList.toggle("bg-none");
                } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I think that this could work. It's great to know that different approaches work for the same goal. Thank You so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I also like the simplicity of your code, and that it's not too far off from my original shows it's not too far off from what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS here, and the classList toggle method is the simplest way.

eg.

```js
document.getElementById("circle").onclick=function() {
  document.getElementById("circle").classList.toggle('toggle');
}
```

```css
#circle {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

#circle.toggle {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll plug it and these other first four suggestions into an iteration of my project and let all of you know how it goes. You've helped me a lot.

Comment: I like that your code is very simple, and does exactly what I need it to do with minimal changes to my original code. ie, it's in line with what I was thinking in terms of ease of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved your background-color CSS to 2 new classes, which would toggle as you click on the div. I hope this resolved your query.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning Javascript</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>
            #circle {
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                border-radius:100px;
            }
            .bg-red {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .bg-blue {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="circle" class="bg-red"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           const circleDiv = document.getElementById("circle");
           circleDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
              circleDiv.classList.toggle('bg-red');
              circleDiv.classList.toggle('bg-blue');
            });
        </script>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I really appreciate your help. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I like the use of the .toggle and => in your solution as I can see it's usefulness in making various toggle switches.